# Implimenting Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I have been given the framework to implement a doubly linked list. I am getting stumped on the PushFront() method. The method should add the provided element to the front of the linked list and it should return the address to the new head node. I am confused about how to access the current head of the list so I can assign it to the pNext pointer. The PushFront() method looks like this so far:

```
Element* Element::PushFront(Element* d){
   Element* newElement = new Element(Data());    // Allocate space for new element
   newElement->ElementData = d->ElementData;    // Assign ElementData to the new  element                
   newElement->pNext = // Head address
   newElement->pPrev = NULL;
return nullptr;
}
```

Element Class Constructor:

```
Element::Element(Data d){
   ElementData = d;
   pNext = NULL;
   pPrev = NULL;
}
```

Data Class:

```
Data::Data(){
Name = "Unknown";
SN = 0;
Program = "Unknown";
}

Data::Data(string NameStr, unsigned int sNumber, string Prog) :
Name(NameStr), SN(sNumber), Program(Prog) {};
```

Main:

```
Element* pList = new Element(Data("Cam", 12345, "Testing1"));   
Element newE(Data("Bob", 335567, "Testing2"));
pList = pList->PushFront(&newE);
```

My understanding is that you would typically provide the address of the head when calling PushFront(), however since I am not provided that I am unsure of how I can access it.

Comment: [Rubber Duckie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what you plan on using `Element* d` for. Just to get the data out of it? There has to be a better use for it or you'd just pass in the data.

Comment: `pList` is the head of the list. Inside the `PushFront` method, `pList` is referred to as `this`.

Comment: @user3386109 THANK YOU. This was my lack of understanding.

Comment: I think you are conflating the linked list with the links in the list. `Element` looks like it should be a link. It should not know what a head is because the only things a link should know is what other links it's been attached to and the data it contains. A Link might be a head, but it shouldn't know that. The head is a detail only the linked list should know. Similar with `PushFront`. A Link shouldn't have a front. It's just got a `prev` and `next`, so perhaps an `insert_before` and an `insert_after`. The linked list, that has a front.

Comment: Sometimes the jester in me fights to come out... so my apologies for this remark: Is the name of the class "leaky c++ 101"? :) If `Element*p` is passed into `PushFront()`, then you could as well write in main: `... Element (Data("Cam", 12345, "Testing1"));`  And then pass the address of the automatic variable. Which in turn would render destruction, removal etc. nigh impossible to implement :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your approach to the list definition the function can look the following way

```
Element * Element::PushFront( Element *d )
{
    Element *newElement = new Element( d->ElementData );

    newElement->pNext = this;
    newElement->pPrev = this->pPrev;
    this->pPrev = newElement;

    return newElement;
}
```

Though such a declaration of the function does not make a great sense. The function should be declared at least like

```
Element * Element::PushFront( const Data &d );
```

instead of

```
Element * Element::PushFront( Element *d );
```

Or even like

```
Element * Element::PushFront( const char *Name, unsigned int SN, const char *Program );
```

Pay attention to that it is much better to declare one more data structure that indeed will represent the doubly-linked list and that will contain pointers to the first (head) and the last (tail) objects of the type Element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused about how to access the current head of the list

As you call the `PushFront` method on the `pList` instance, the `this` reference will be `pList`, which is assumed to be the head of the list. The main program is responsible for maintaining a reference to the head.

Note that sometimes another class is created for representing the list, which then has a `head` member. However, in this case, you seem not to have such a class, and the main program must manage the head itself, i.e. `pList`.

The `PushFront` method must then "help" the main program in doing this, and return the reference to the *new* head. So don't return `nullptr`.

I don't really understand why in `PushFront` you create a new `Element`, since you already get an element passed as argument. I would think the purpose is to add *that* element to the list, and not a copy of it.

So:

```
Element* Element::PushFront(Element* d){
   d->pNext = this;
   d->pPrev = NULL;
   return d;
}
```

In the main program I would suggest creating both `Element` instances with `new`, so that their memory management is the same:

```
Element* pList = new Element(Data("Cam", 12345, "Testing1"));   
Element* newE = new Element(Data("Bob", 335567, "Testing2"));
pList = pList->PushFront(newE);
```